# find discount corresponding to price using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

The price corresponding to discount are below:

```
price   discount(%)
100      10
200      15
450      20
800      25
1000     30
1250     40
```

900 is not in table but we can see 900 is exist between 800 to 1000 so I want to show discount 25% for price = 900.

Comment: You might want to add an actual question including explanation what you want to accomplish, what the result would be, what you have tried etc. And also which SQL database you are using.

Comment: This question will be quickly closed unless you show that you have tried *something* instead of just dumping data on us....

Comment: Please provide some details in the question. What is the requirement, what is the input?, what is the expcted output and what have you tried?

Comment: `SELECT discount from TableName Where price = 900`  ???

Comment: Linear Interpolation? 27.5?

Comment: what's the logic behind this?

Comment: I am confuse how to find unknown range for selecting particular row from table. like I want to find discount of item that price is 900 but 900 is not in table but we can see 900 is exist between 800 to 1000 so I want to show discount 25%.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to retrieve the discount that is closed to the given amount. The way to do this is to select all discounts that are smaller or the same as the given price, order them highest price first and then only return the first row.

It all sounds more complicated than it actually is:

```
SELECT discount 
FROM [tableName] 
WHERE price <= 900 
ORDER BY price DESC 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: thanks, its working for me.

Comment: @rajendrakumar - that doesn't make sense. You tagged your post "oracle" yet you say LIMIT 1 works for you? What version of Oracle is that? (Seriously: there is no "LIMIT 1" in Oracle; and the best answer to your question depends on your Oracle version.)

Comment: Well that tag wasn't there when I replied... sounds like magic